# How to get fast result in Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql query that i need to run. But it takes forever to execute. Can anybody help me to simplify my mysql query.

```
SELECT w.workorderno, w.assetno, 
FORMAT(SUM((SELECT COALESCE(SUM(wl.tothour),0) FROM workorderlabor wl WHERE wl.workorderno = w.workorderno)),2) AS 'Total Man Hours', 
FORMAT(SUM((SELECT COALESCE(SUM(wl.totcost),0) FROM workorderlabor wl WHERE wl.workorderno = w.workorderno)),2) AS 'Total Labor Cost', 
FORMAT(SUM((SELECT COALESCE(SUM(wi.price*wi.quantity),0) FROM inventory_issuances wi WHERE wi.work_order_id = w.workorderno)),2) AS 'Total Part Cost',
FORMAT(SUM((SELECT COALESCE(SUM(wl.totcost),0) FROM workorderlabor wl WHERE wl.workorderno = w.workorderno) + 
(SELECT COALESCE(SUM(wi.price*wi.quantity),0) FROM inventory_issuances wi WHERE wi.work_order_id = w.workorderno)),2) AS 'Grand Total'
FROM workorders w
GROUP BY w.assetno
```

Comment: What does the definition of `workorders` look like? Especially, what keys and indices does it have?

Comment: Pleas publish all table definitions , sample data and expected outcome as text AND what does  takes forever to execute mean, how many rows, local or remote server..

Comment: You must use separate aggregating subqueries in FROM, not correlated ones in SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

Arguably simpler, but possibly not faster:

```
SELECT  w.workorderno, w.assetno,
        FORMAT(COALESCE(SUM(man_hours), 0), 2)  AS 'Total Man Hours',
        FORMAT(COALESCE(SUM(labor_cost), 0), 2) AS 'Total Labor Cost',
        FORMAT(COALESCE(SUM(part_cost), 0), 2)  AS 'Total Part Cost',
        FORMAT(COALESCE(SUM(labor_cost+part_cost), 0), 2) AS 'Grand Total'
    FROM  workorders w
    JOIN ( SELECT  workorderno,
                   SUM(wl.tothour) AS man_hours,
                   SUM(wl.totcost) AS labor_cost
               FROM  workorderlabor wl
               GROUP BY workorderno ) AS o
         ) AS i  ON i.workorderno = w.workorderno
    JOIN ( SELECT  work_order_id,
                   SUM(wi.price*wi.quantity) AS parts_cost
               FROM  inventory_issuances wi
         ) AS i  ON i.work_order_id = w.workorderno
    GROUP BY  w.assetno
```

How many rows in each table?

These indexes may help with performance:

```
workorderlabor:  INDEX(workorderno,  tothour)
workorderlabor:  INDEX(workorderno,  totcost)
inventory_issuances:  INDEX(work_order_id)
```